Resize Macintosh HD macOS Sequoia




As you can see I have 3,84 TB free space, how can I merge this Free Space to my Macintosh HD?
Any ideas?
Many thanks for your time

Post the output from the command diskutil list.

Yah we need more info like @David Anderson mentioned. And off the top of my head that partition AFTER your Mac hard drive will need to go away as it is between your (presumed) Mac HD and all that free space. But don't do anything till we have seen the output of diskutil.

Output for the command diskutil list added
